# Android, problem (bug) with my app in recents apps (Task Manager)

Tags: android

[image: Image, This is inside recent apps]

The problem is when i close my app (Not destroy, but its in recents apps) and when i reopen my app from the recents it's like there are 2 activities, 1 that's open the app and 1 is slide to the left behind the other 1. But if i open recent apps again there is only 1. It happens only when click on the app inside recent apps.

I can't find the problem.
Someone knows what cause this problem. If you need more info, let me know, hope someone has seen this before.
See image.

Im tying to get adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger soon, im new to that.

See manifest below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="nl.bouwman.syntess">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/dkc_backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="barcode" />

    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|locale"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/FlashTheme.Settings">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".chat.MainChatActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".chat.ChattyActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".chat.SettingsChatActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ProfileActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".chat.FindFriendsActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity android:name=".chat.GroupChatActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.NextActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MeldingActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.HtmlSourceActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.BookMarkActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|locale"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme" />

    <activity
        android:name=".rssstatus.SyntessStatus"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeWithCorners"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity android:name=".activity.ImageDetailActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />

    <activity android:name=".koudemapfirebase.KoudeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|locale"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme" />

    <activity android:name=".koudemapfirebase.KoudeActivityFull"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|locale"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme" />

    <activity android:name=".koudemapfirebase.BarcodeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|locale"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:theme="@style/DKCTheme" />

    <service
        android:name=".servicejob.WerkBonJobService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="@string/notifications"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <service
        android:name=".servicejob.VersieJobService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <service
        android:name=".downloadservice.DownloadService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

    <service
        android:name=".servicejob.DkcFirebaseIdService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".service.NotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".downloadservice.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.nl.bouwman.syntess.DOWNLOAD_STARTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.nl.bouwman.syntess.DOWNLOAD_FINISHED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.nl.bouwman.syntess.DOWNLOAD_CANCELLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AboutActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Kau.About" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to share the output of `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` command?

Comment: You mean the logcat from android studio?

Comment: Can you share the manifest file please?

Comment: @Robin You'll need ADB via a terminal for that. See if it's possible after referring [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys).

Comment: See Edited post.

Comment: Hey Robin, could you please edit your post and clarify what it is exactly that you're asking? If you can narrow it down into a single concise question, you're more likely to find people who can help you out :)